# Posted SWF Video using opengraph does not play inline on Facebook user Feed

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph, inline, feed

When I post a SWF video using opengraph on my Facebook wall programatically the post is updated on my feed together with a link that opens a new window that plays the SWF. The desired result is the post with a little play button that plays the swf inline instead of opening a window. I have browsed around and tested all options for about two months month now and seen similar questions, and even a bug report which seemed closed but unresolved.

If I post a soundcloud  link as a status message (and also in my code using open graph) it works, but when I make my own, it posts but as a static image and no play button. I have used the object debugger on my url below

[Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://webapp.platinumcredit.co.ke/gumzo/ochieng)

on my website and all seems the same as the object debugger for the soundcloud one below

[Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://soundcloud.com/chris-ochieng/testing)

There must be something that I am missing but I don't know what it is. I hope this will help other developers save two months of their life.

There are also other questions about SSL playback, and I have gone through them and modified as they have suggested but the result is the same. I have also added the suggested tags (og:video and fb:app_id) , still the same.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

That was an older issue the solution can be found on this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/602/

Basically what you need to do is the following:

```
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/awesome.swf"/>
```

and I would recommend that you use both http and https links.

Comment: Yes, they had fixed the problem. It actually was a problem on FB side of things. All is working well now.